# change dataProvider in amChart Serial based on zoom event

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to change the dataProvider associated to an amChart Serial graph based on the zoom lavel. The idea is straightforward: I have 2 set of data, the hourly has a value for each hour in a year, the daily has a value for each day. I start with daily precision, when a user zoom under 35 days I want to switch to hourly precision.

This is the listener

```
chart.addListener("zoomed", function (event) {
    if (event.endDate - event.startDate > 3000000000 && chart.dataProvider == dataHourly) {
        chart.dataProvider = dataDaily;
    }
    else if (event.endDate - event.startDate <= 3000000000 && chart.dataProvider == dataDaily) {
        chart.dataProvider = dataHourly;
    }

    // now I need to "commit"
}
```

This part works fine, now I need to update the graph. The functions to be used should be

```
chart.validateData();
chart.animateAgain();
```

The problem is that once I try to apply the `dataHourly` dataProvider the zoom is reset, so it goes back to a value > 3000000000 and `dataDaily` are re-applied. I need to manually set the `startDate` and `endDate` in the event but... how can I do? Is there something like this (non working) code?

```
// now I need to "commit"
chart.startDate = event.startDate;
chart.endDate= event.endDate;
chart.validateData();
chart.animateAgain();
```

Comment: Try setting `zoomOutOnDataUpdate: false`.

Comment: @martynasma thank you for the hint, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Any chance of seeing your complete code and data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary fix I changed `chart.validateData();` with `chart.validateNow(true, true);`. It prevents event propagation but I experienced glitches while zooming out.

Anyway the support helped me to find out the correct way to prevent zoom reset by handling also `dataUpdated` event instead of stopping all events propagation. [HERE](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamically-changing-granularity-data-based-zoom-scope/) is a working sample where event `dataUpdated` is properly managed to avoid zoom reset (of course also `zoomed` event need to be handled properly to set `chart.ignoreZoomEvent` correctly )